# Querying to get the ObjectID of the Project through Rally Rest API in java

Tags: java, rally

Am trying with the below code to get the ObjectID of the Project by using Project's FormattedID...but am getting no results. Please let me know, where am getting wrong.

```
String projectFormattedID = "EH-HELLO-WORLD";
    QueryRequest projectRequest = new QueryRequest("project");
    storyRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("ObejctID"));
    storyRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", projectFormattedID));
    QueryResponse storyQueryResponse = restApi.query(storyRequest);
    System.out.println(storyQueryResponse.getResults());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo in your fetch.  It should be:

```
storyRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("ObjectID"));
```

Also, you can always get the ObjectID by parsing it out of the _ref attribute, which is always rendered on all responses:

```
String objectId = Ref.getOidFromRef(storyObject.get("_ref").getAsString());
```

Comment: Got the results when i changed the query filter as below:

`storyRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=",             projectFormattedID));`